# filter MyDjango data based on condition and calculation in django

Tags: mysql, django

```
class Student():
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    surname=models.CharField(max_length=200)


class groupA():
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    math=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)
    english=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)
    biology=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)
    chemistry=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)
```

How to filter the ready list based on type_1 > 2 and type_2 < 1  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this,

```
result = groupA.objects.annotate(
    type_1=F('math') / F('english'),
    type_2=F('chemistry') / F('math'),
).filter(type_1__gt=2, type_2__lt=1)
```

Comment: Since this post already answered the issue, please do ask a new question :)